# How can I implement ODM rules engine in place of item processor in Spring Batch/Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, ibm-odm

I am new to both Spring Batch and ODM Rules Engine. Currently I have a Spring Batch application that imports data into an xml file from excel .csv file. The Spring Batch is written in Java using an Eclipse - Maven Project. Now that I was able to successfully read the file and write it to xml, I would like to run rules using the ODM rules engine. I have a rules project in eclipse but I am not sure how to call it in the Spring batch (or vice versa). I do not necessarily need to output it to xml as long as I can export the data somehow.

Comment: If you vote to close the question please provide a comment as to why. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Potential Solution:

1. Create XOM with class where the class in the Spring Batch has the properties that will be executed with the ODM Rules Engine. (Complete)
2. Create ODM Rules Project where the XOM in (1) is called and create rules. (Complete)
3. Compile ODM Rule Project int a jar file. (Next Step)
4. Call the jar file into the Spring Batch file and implement as the item processor. (Next Step)

Will update as I go along.